# How can I apply logical positivism in the philosophy of education?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, logical-positivism, education

How can I apply logical positivism in the philosophy of education?

How would I use logical positivism to explore why teachers teach (objectives), what should be taught (curriculum) and how should the curriculum be taught (teaching strategies)?

Comment: I made some edits to focus on the question. You may roll these back or continue editing. You can see the versions by clicking on the "edited" link above. Welcome to this SE!

Comment: Can you add a bit of context to explain why you think logical positivism is relevant in philosophy of education? Also, welcome to the site.

Comment: Could you tell us a bit about where this idea came from? [Logical positivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_positivism) (is this what you mean?) is a bit obsolete a philosophy, applying it today does not usually come up.

Comment: For example:Why teach? (Concept)                                                    Teachers teach for learners to distinguish between sense and nonsense, knowledge and ignorance, meaningful and meaningless propositions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use logical positivism in the philosophy of education?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/54975/how-can-i-use-logical-positivism-in-the-philosophy-of-education) Please do not post duplicate questions.