# How can I use logical positivism in the philosophy of education?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, logical-positivism

Logical Positivism is a teacher centered philosophy that rejects intuition, matters of mind, essences, and inner causes. This philosophy relies on laws of matter and motion as valid, and bases truth on provable fact.

How can I apply logical positivism in the philosophy of education? How would I use logical positivism to explore why teachers teach (objectives), what should be taught (curriculum) and how should the curriculum be taught (teaching strategies)? What is the importance of logical positivism in teaching-learning process?

Comment: How logical positivism was presented to America "at large" was by fact-value. And this was one concept that caught on like wildfire, and it's still out there. Still viable.  So did the logical positivists win?  In a sense, yes.

Comment: is logical positivism an opposite of existentialism?

Comment: Is it like existentialism?  No. I mean it answers a different set of problems. I will try to find a YouTube for you which features an older A.J. Ayer.

Comment: I recommend that you watch this a few times and listen carefully. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nG0EWNezFl4

Comment: (I mention behaviorism above because behavior can be observed, and observed by more than one person, it is "objective", and therefore we don't have to guess what goes on in another's mind. )

Comment: this is our class project. our teacher ask us to do a research about LP and apply it on teaching.

Comment: Well if it's an assignment you have to do it, whether it's outdated or not. A.J. Ayer talks so fast he is hard to understand. What he says about Method is important.  Essentially the kids should be taught an empirical method. I have made too many comments and I will have to remove some of them.

Comment: Oddly enough, this book may help. He discusses is the book how to make a report. "Reporter mode" essentially. Hayakawa, S. I. Language in Thought and Action. 1939. Enlarged ed. San Diego: Harcourt Brace Jovanovich, 1978. Originally published as Language in Action.  You may want to look for it in a college library.  It does not mention logical positivism directly, but it uses some ideas from logical positivism. Good luck.

Comment: Your philosophy of education will require that you tell students that philosophy is incomprehensible and a waste of time. Do you really want to do this? One quibble -your question states that LP bases truth on provable fact but this is not the case. It adopts an interpretation of the facts of metaphysics that is optional and renders it futile. I feel theories used in education should be less whacky.   .

Answer (score 1):

Logical positivism up and died many years ago, though some features of it continue to echo in current philosophical thinking. It is likely that your teacher has in mind some more general features of analytical philosophy in the English-speaking tradition. These include:

- An emphasis on paying attention to empirical data rather than fancy
  mystical ideas.
- Giving an important place to science as against tradition or
  authority as sources of information.
- Focusing on  conjectures that are testable, rather than engaging in
  ad hoc theorising.
- Making use of formal logic wherever possible to illuminate and
  clarify ideas.
- Preferring analysis and critical thinking to obfuscation.
- Challenging commonly held views, especially one's own.
- Searching for flaws in one's views by engaging with those who
  disagree.

If you teach your students these things, you will be doing them a service.

Answer (score 0):

> Logical Positivism is a teacher centered philosophy that rejects intuition, matters of mind, essences, and inner causes. This philosophy relies on laws of matter and motion as valid, and bases truth on provable fact.

You haven't described your position very clearly so it is a bit difficult to say much about it. But what you have written so far is inconsistent.

Laws of motion can't be proven. Such laws constrain the motion of every physical object in the universe at all times. There is lots of motion we can't observe that could deviate from those laws of motion, e.g. - motion in the core of the sun, so those laws could be false. So those laws can't be shown to be true or probably true or good or anything like that - they can't be proven.

Since your description of this philosophy is inconsistent it can't be applied to teaching or to anything else.

Comment: How is this relevant to education? And "relies on laws of matter and motion as valid" says nothing about "proving", there is nothing inconsistent about relying on unproven or even unprovable beliefs (like religion or falsificationism). As for "provable facts", the standards for "proving" them are pretty low, reporters are satisfied with a couple of witnesses, for example. So it is hard to see what the point of your post here is.

Comment: @Conifold If LP relies on only using provable fact, and it uses laws of motion, then it is self contradictory since laws of motion are not provable facts. I don't think being unprovable is a reason to avoid using an idea, but that is completely irrelevant to the consistency of the poster's ideas. and if the poster's ideas aren't consistent they can't be applied to education or to anything else.

Comment: Inconsistent ideas have been applied for centuries, occasionally with success, pragmatic utility does not require consistency. And OP's phrasing only mentions relying on "laws of matter and motion", not them being "provable facts". And "provable" they may well be, for that matter, since we are not told what "provable" means.

Comment: Inconsistent ideas have not been applied since it is impossible to apply them. Rather, people have decided what to do in an ad hoc way according to their own preferences using parts of inconsistent ideas as excuses for their actions. Even where where this ad hockery works it prevents flaws in ideas from being recognised and corrected. And where such ad hoc decisions don't work it's difficult to work out why they didn't work.
The poster sez that truth is based on provable fact, so the truth of the laws of motion requires them to be provable in this position.

Comment: The poster's lack of an explanation of what provable means is a point against his position, not a point in its favour. It's better for everyone involved to be clear and say to the poster that his position is vague, apparently inconsistent and inapplicable than to make excuses for it.

Comment: Your psychoanalysis of people's motivations is neither verifiable nor falsifiable nor particularly insightful, personal idiosyncrasies are best kept off this site. And the OP does not have a "position", they can barely express themselves, let alone appreciate a long obsolete debate between positivists and Popper.

Comment: @Conifold It's impossible to act on an inconsistent idea. So a person who claims to be acting on such an idea has already dragged his personal idiosyncrasies onto this site. Since he has made the topic relevant by his conduct it is silly to bar discussion of that topic unless you're going to delete the whole question.
Also, if a person brings up logical positivism, any unrefuted criticisms of LP by anyone, including Popper, are relevant.

Comment: "*Laws of motion can't be proven.*" The OP never implied they can. Instead, the OP pointed out the axiomatic nature of those laws in Logical Positivism (specifically: "*This philosophy **relies on** laws of matter and motion **as valid***", emphasis added). If anything, your criticism is as flawed as positing that a theorem ought to be discarded merely on grounds of the impossibility to prove the axioms on which that theorem is based. I see no inconsistency in the OP's description.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I use logical positivism to explore why teachers teach (objectives), what should be taught (curriculum) and how should the curriculum be taught (teaching strategies)?

The scope of a positivistic inquiry is limited to what is susceptible to observation. That observation typically is in terms of relations or interactions between the elements involved. Accordingly, the inquiry cannot ascertain notions such as a teacher's ulterior motive for teaching, nor the contents and structure of an objectively ideal curriculum. That is because such notions are inextricable from intuition, and from the impossible grasping of the inner cause(s) or substance of something external to the observer. This leads to answers which are rather of a pragmatic and/or utilitarian nature.

By way of example, the answer to "*why teachers teach*" may point to the foreseeable socio-economic benefits (i.e., prestige, salary) that tend to improve teachers' position or circumstances. That tentative answer will be either reinforced or weakened as [in-]consistent with subsequent observations.

Positivism is not infallible, though. A teacher's ulterior motive might be something else (for instance, an aversion to any other professions). The teacher's ability to conceal from everyone that ulterior motive would mislead the inquirer's interpretations of the relations observed. But Positivism is straight-forward by explicitly excluding beforehand the aspiration of ascertaining the essence or substance of the matter at issue.